# Namespace and Classes - Resolving Naming Ambiguity

Tags: c#, namespaces

The issue I'm getting is "namespace is being used as a type" in a C# project. I get why it's happening and I understand what I have to do to fix it. But it makes little sense to me and so the question here is understanding the design of namespaces and classes in C# context.

I'm hoping this question is different enough from others because I'm not asking how to resolve the situation, but rather how to keep logical and relevant naming while dealing with the situation as I describe it.

I have followed MSDN conventions for naming solutions. So I have a solution called:

```
TesterStories.Voxam
```

I have two projects within that. One is `TesterStories.Voxam.App` and looks like this:

```
namespace TesterStories.Voxam.App
{
    TesterStories.Voxam.Parser parser = new TesterStories.Voxam.Parser();

    class Program
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is in that third line.

Presumably because I have another project called `TesterStories.Voxam.Parser`, which looks like this:

```
namespace TesterStories.Voxam.Parser
{
    public class Parser
    {
    }
}
```

So is it saying that it doesn't like that I have "Parser" in my namespace for the project?

But according to MSDN guidelines, if the Parser is the feature, then that's what I should be calling the namespace: `[Company].[Project].[Feature]`. The class is `Parser` because, after all, that's what the class does.

So it seems like what I have to do is this:

```
namespace TesterStories.Voxam.Parser
{
    public class Xyzzy
    {
    }
}
```

So here I changed my `Parser` class to `Xyzzy` class. Now back in my file that was causing the problem I can do this:

```
using TesterStories.Voxam.Parser;

namespace TesterStories.Voxam.App
{
    class Program
    {
        Xyzzy parser = new Xyzzy();
    }
}
```

So I get it -- but it means I have to change my class to be something it's not. I realize I could call it `AppParser` or `ParserApp` or whatever.

In this context, what do developers tend to do? Do you change your namespace or do you change your class? Even though, in my case, I'm describing the feature as per MSDN guidelines and correctly naming the class based on what it does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespaces and class names aren't the problem here.
In your original code, you need to designate what class from the TesterStories.Voxam.Parser namespace this 'parser' object should be.

Your original code:

```
TesterStories.Voxam.Parser parser = new TesterStories.Voxam.Parser();
```

What class/type in the TesterStories.Voxam.Parser namespace is this supposed to be?

You would need to do:

```
TesterStories.Voxam.Parser.*Parser* parser = new TesterStories.Voxam.Parser.*Parser*();
```

(* added for emphasis :) )

Or, like you did in your last code snippet, add a using statement:

```
using TesterStories.Voxam.Parser;
```

So that you can do:

```
Parser parser = new Parser();
```

Edit - More complete example (for the 'using' suggestion):

```
namespace TesterStories.Voxam.App
{
    using TesterStories.Voxam.Parser;

    class Program
    {
        Parser parser = new Parser();
    }
}

namespace TesterStories.Voxam.Parser
{
    public class Parser
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I get the first part. Regarding the second part (after your "or"), if I have `using TesterStories.Voxam.Parser;` in my file and do this: `Parser parser = new Parser();` in the class ... that does not work. I get 'Parser is a namespace but is used like a type.'

I just want to make sure I'm not misreading your second part there. But, again, I see the point of your first part.

Comment: Ah, but I could do this: `Parser.Parser parser = new Parser.Parser();` Interesting. Coming from a Java background, this is a bit of cognitive friction for me. I still feel like I have to name something what it isn't (at some level) just so I don't have to repeat ("Parser.Parser"). However, that's my problem, not anyone else's! Thank you for your response.

Comment: @JeffNyman See if the edit to the answer helps any (as you shouldn't have to repeat the "Parser.Parser").

Comment: Got it! That makes sense. Much appreciated.